# excel vba date formatting - for loop

Tags: vba, excel, date

How do you loop through the entire column and check if it is full year format or full date format and change every cell to full date format. For example, if a cell is 1832, how do you make it 1/1/1832 so the format is consistent throughout the column Q

Comment: It looks like this is a duplicate question.
Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30856268/4974853)

Comment: And also [this!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742990/change-in-date-when-importing-excel-to-access-db#comment49576676_30742990)  Further, you should note that Excel will not recognize dates prior to 1/1/1900, so for 1/1/1832 you will need a text format, and right alignment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXCEL VBA - Date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853933/excel-vba-date-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Range("Q1").End(xlDown).Row
   If Not IsDate(Cells(i, 17).Value) Then
       Cells(i, 17).Value = "1/1/" & Cells(i, 17).Value
   End If  
Next i
```

IsDate function returns "true" if the passed value is a date. If the cell value is not a date, Concatenate "1/1" to the cell value. (17 represents column Q)

Comment: I tested and it worked fine. Where exactly it shows error? Can you show some sample data ?